# How to use my own suggestions on TextView?

Tags: android

I'm pretty new to Android and Java and I can't find a good answer for this question.

Can I implement my own suggestions for user input with no search functionality? I mean, I need to override the suggestions for a specific input field because I know what the user will be writing and storing, but it's not a search field.

Searching about the subject always returns questions about search fields, which isn't the case.

Thank you.

Comment: you mean u want to implement auto suggestion? yes u can

Comment: I mean I want to override the auto suggestions with my own dictionary. Is there a way? Any direction on how to achieve that?

Comment: Yes, there's definitely a way, I've done something like that. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: Hello Selvin and Bill the Lizard, this was my first question, it's not nice to be blocked because of my first "mistake". It's all a matter of translation from my native language. I accept that you are right but because of that one negative point I can't give answers and to be fair, it's pretty hard to get points without answers. So, how can I become positive again if I can't give answers? I don't have new questions... Please, unblock me for asnwering!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AutoCompleteTextView (in the API as an extension of EditText) and provide your words (dictionary) in the adapter:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: Thank you great Dan. Now I see it's a simple thing but every time I searched for it I found only suggestions for search widget.